# Run as Administrator Bat File/ Cmd File Windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following cmd command:

```
C:\Users\spidey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python C:\Users\spidey\Documents\sleepScript\textdocument.py
```

Inside a `.bat` file. When I double click and run it, it runs well but when I try to right click and `run as administrator` it just opens the window and closes adruptly without completing the execution.

The end result of the command is a text file which is created in first case but not when I try to run it as administrator.

The reason for this to run as adminstrator is because I will be running it on cloud and so there it runs as administrator.

Here are the content of `textdocument.py`:

```
import datetime
file = open('read.txt', 'w') 
file.write('Executed @ ' + str(datetime.datetime.now())) 
file.close()
```

Here is another update:
Tried to create a shortcut and setup it's advanced property as run as administrator. But that doesn't work as well.
[image]

After doing this, I tried to run the `.bat` file again as administrator but no effect.

As suggested in the comments, I shifted all the files to C: drive so that it's accesible to everyone. But unfortunately that didn't work as well window just opens and aprubtly closes without giving the end result. On the other hand normal running works here as well.

Here is the command:

`C:\Python\Python39\python C:\uiPath\textdocument.py`

Comment: It's pretty tough to say what's wrong when we don't get to see `testdocument.py`. The problem is most likely that the administrator account doesn't have access to `C:\users\spidey`. Don't put files that you want others to access in your own user directory.

Comment: So do you recommend it putting inside C drive directly? Btw python is installed within the C:\users\spidey So do you want me to make a copy of the same in C drive too and then try? And yeah! I have added the content of testdocument.py

Comment: Your python install shouldn't be in your user folder if you expect anyone other than you to be using it. This is pretty common information - if you put things in your own user account, other users cannot access those files. It's the entire purpose of having your own directory. Think about it: *I have this place that I can put my own personal files. Why can't someone other than me see those files?". If you want others to be able to access them, put them in a shared folder like "C:\users\public".

Comment: that's true but why not the administrator can access it? Is it something like other user files even admins can't access?

Comment: Admin users have to confirm that they want to access other user's files. It's not an automatic permission. Don't use your personal folder to hold shared files. Use the Public folder. I don't know any other way to say it - I've said it three times now. See my first comment: "Don't put files that you want others to access in your own user directory" and my second "if you want others to be able to access them, put them in a shared folder".

Comment: I see.... sorry for asking you again and again the same thing. So I did try to run it after putting everything in c drive from where it can be accessed by anyone. Here is the bat command: `"C:\Python\Python39\python C:\uiPath\textdocument.py"` This continues to run on double click but fails to run when trying to run as administrator.

Comment: @ShivamSahil What is the current directory set to when you run it?

Comment: @dxiv Oh Yes actually that was the miss.... I think it was running correctly but was storing the results in its initial current directory, just added `os.chdir(path)` to sort the issue. Seems like it had nothing to do with the command prompt but more with the setup of current Dir. Thanks @dxiv.

Answer (score 0):

After a long debugging, I realized that the command was actually running correctly. It's all that it was saving the file into the other default directory after adding in my python script:

`os.chdir(path)`

Where path is the path where I wanted it to store. Whereas in case of double clicking and running it, by default that path was set to the path where the file was located in.

The problem got fixed. Thank you everyone for the help!